# .NET HttpClient throws "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" exception while calling endpoint with certificate

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, ssl-certificate

I am calling a remote HTTPS endpoint using .net6.0 HttpClient with a certificate in .p12 format. I am loading the certificate from a file and adding the certificate using `handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);`

- When I call the endpoint from localhost, an exception is thrown:

  > The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed, see inner exception. The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted`.
- When I call the endpoint from localhost and I have the certificate installed, everything is ok.
- When I run code as Azure Function exception is thrown.

  > Exception while executing function: Function1 The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed, see inner exception. The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.`.

I have tried to add the certificate to Azure Function Certificates using *Certificated (preview)* tab like .pfx certificate (renaming .p12 to .pfx is enough, on localhost it is working) but with no result.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem with this exception?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can't use just any certificate, it has to be from a source trusted by *the clients*. Otherwise a hacker could intercept traffic by putting their own proxy in front of your service using their own untrusted certificate. Installing your own self-trusted certificate to Azure Functions won't make any client trust it. Using the `devcerts` command adds your self-signed certificate to the trusted list on your machine only

Comment: Have you tried to set the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` of your handler and just write few lines of code that accept this particular cert? Sorry if this doesn't apply, not sure if you have issues with server or client cert.

Comment: `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` is generally a bad idea, although it can be useful for debugging. Either way, can you not get your hands on a cert from a publicly trusted authority?

Comment: `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` is not even called, exception is thrown before the call. Why it works when I install the certificate and do not works when I remove certificate from windows? I thought that it does not matter when I am loading certificate from file. I think that certificate is provided by trusted authority, otherwise it would not be working in all cases.